# How to make fluentd send logs to Loki from the last dynamically created folder

Tags: grafana, fluentd

At the moment I collect all multiline logs and visualize them on the Grafana dashboard. And now I need to get logs from the last dynamically created folder and visualize them on the separate Grafana dashboard.
The folders are created dynamically each time when the application is started.

logs path is the next:

```
/var/log/2021-01-13/12_57_12_201/
/var/log/2021-01-13/12_54_48_123/
/var/log/2021-01-14/11_15_23_849/11_15_23_849_A.log
/var/log/2021-01-14/11_15_23_849/11_15_23_849_B.log
/var/log/2021-01-14/11_15_23_849/11_15_23_849_C.log
/var/log/2021-01-14/11_15_23_849/11_15_23_849_D.log
```

I use the docker-compose file to start grafana:7.3.3, fluent-plugin-loki:latest and loki:2.1.0, and fluent.conf file to collect all logs and send them to Loki.
Is it possible to collect logs from the last dynamically created folder? And how is it possible to do?

Here is my fluent.conf file:

```
<source>
   @type tail
   @log_level debug
   path /var/log/%Y-%m-%d/*/*.log
   pos_file  /var/log/pos/positions.log.pos
   tag varlog.*
   path_key filename
   multiline_flush_interval 5s
   refresh_interval 1s
   read_from_head true
   follow_inodes true
   <parse>
      @type multiline
      format_firstline /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<message>.+)$/
      format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<message>.+)$/
      time_key               time
      time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      timezone               +0200
    </parse>
</source>

<match varlog.**>
  @type loki
  url "http://loki:3100"
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 1s
    chunk_limit_size 1m
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>
  extra_labels {"job":"applogs", "agent":"fluentd"}
  <label>
    filename
  </label>
</match>
```

After I change my configuration with using fluentd exec input plugin I receive next information in fluentd log:
`fluent/log.rb:302:debug: Executing command title=:exec_input spawn=[{}, "sh /var/log/folderParser.sh"] mode=[:read] stderr=:discard`
It appeare every time when bash script should be started.

My current fluent.config file with exec input plugin has the next configuration:

```
<source>
   @type exec
   command sh /var/log/folderParser.sh
   tag newlog.*
   run_interval 10s
   <parse>
      @type none
   </parse>
</source>

<source>
   @type tail
   @log_level debug
   path /var/log/lastLogs/*.log
   pos_file  /var/log/pos/positions.log.pos
   tag newlog.*
   path_key filename
   multiline_flush_interval 5s
   refresh_interval 1s
   read_from_head true
   <parse>
      @type multiline
      format_firstline /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<message>.+)$/
      format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<message>.+)$/
      time_key               time
      time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      timezone               +0200
    </parse>
</source>

<match newlog.**>
  @type loki
  url "http://loki:3100"
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 1s
    chunk_limit_size 1m
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>
  extra_labels {"job":"applogs", "agent":"fluentd", "datacenter":"lastlogs"}
  <label>
    filename
  </label>
</match>
```

Also here is the script that should be performed by exec plugging (its path /var/log/). All logs are here path /var/log/%Y-%m-%d/time_when_app_started/*.log

```
# Remove all existing files from the previous run
rm -r lastLogs

# Move to the needed folder - var
cd ../

# Find last created folder in log directory
date_folder=`ls -ltr ./log | grep '^d' | tail -1| awk '{print $NF}'`
cd log/
# Find last created folder in last date directory
last_created_folder=`ls -ltr ./$date_folder | grep '^d' | tail -1| awk '{print $NF}'`

mkdir lastLogs
#sleep 1m
cp ./$date_folder/$last_created_folder/* ./lastLogs
```

The latest bash script

```
pwd
cd /var/
pwd

# Find last created folder in log directory
date_folder=`ls -ltr ./log | grep '^d' | tail -1| awk '{print $NF}'`
echo $date_folder

# Change directory to log dir to be able to find the last created folder with the logs
cd log/
pwd

# Find last created folder in last date directory
last_created_folder=`ls -ltr ./$date_folder | grep '^d' | tail -1| awk '{print $NF}'`
echo $last_created_folder
# Find last created folder within time directories
path=$date_folder/$last_created_folder
echo $path

# Check if /lastLogs/logs directory contains last logs
if diff ./$date_folder/$last_created_folder/ ./lastLogs/logs/
then
    echo "Files are the same"
#    cp -u ./$date_folder/$last_created_folder/* ./lastLogs/logs

else
    echo "Files or files scope are different"
    rm -r ./lastLogs/logs/*
    cp -u ./$date_folder/$last_created_folder/* ./lastLogs/logs
    echo "Files are reload"
fi
```

Here is my fluent.conf file

```
<source>
    @type exec
    command sh /var/log/folderParser.sh
    tag exec.*
    run_interval 1s
    <parse>
       @type none
    </parse>
</source>

<match exec.*>
  @type stdout
</match>

<source>
   @type tail
   @log_level debug
   path /var/log/lastLogs/logs/*.log
   pos_file  /var/log/pos/positions.log.pos
   tag newlog.*
   path_key filename
   multiline_flush_interval 5s
   refresh_interval 1s
   read_from_head true
   <parse>
      @type multiline
      format_firstline /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<message>.+)$/
      format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<message>.+)$/
      time_key               time
      time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      timezone               +0200
    </parse>
</source>

<match newlog.**>
  @type loki
  url "http://loki:3100"
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 1s
    chunk_limit_size 1m
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>
  extra_labels {"job":"applogs", "agent":"fluentd", "datacenter":"lastlogs"}
  <label>
    filename
  </label>
</match>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit "the last dynamically created folder"? Only the folder that was created at the end or every time a new folder is created?

Comment: I mean  that every time a new folder is created fluentd should send logs from this folder

Comment: Right. How does your current configuration look like? Please add that to your question.

Comment: config file added to the description

Comment: Good. So, what is its current behavior? As I understood it, you want to look for new folders too, right? Isn't `path` already doing that for you with `*` in it that it includes the newly created folders and files in that path? See: https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#path.

Comment: Yes, with the current configuration I have the possibility to collect all logs that were received. But now I need to change this configuration in such a way so I could receive only the logs from the last run. The folder for each new application run is created each time when the application is started (with the name of start time), so I don't know what name it would have the next time. As a result, I don't know where the logs will be and from where I should read them.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. The application generates log files in different folders. You are interested only in the latest one, right?

Comment: Yes, I need only the last one.

Comment: One possible solution could be to use the [exec](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/exec) input plugin using a shell script. The shell script will evaluate and move the latest files to a predefined folder e.g. `/some/path/to/logs/`. You can `tail` this predefined path for new files. You can route the output of `exec` to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I am trying to use the exec input plugin. During this, I have faced the issue that the bash script is not executed by config file, but I can execute it manually. Maybe you have some thoughts regarding this?

here is exec configuration

`<source>
   @type exec
   command sh /var/log/folderParser.sh
   tag none
   run_interval 1s
   <parse>
      @type none
   </parse>
</source>`

Comment: What do you mean by "the bash script is not executed by config file, but I can execute it manually"?

Comment: I mean that if I start this script directly from the folder (sh folderParser.sh in the folder /var/log) it is working as expected, but if I start it via exec input plugin it is not started and nothing from it is performed.

Comment: In fluentd log I receive next message:

fluent/log.rb:302:debug: Executing command title=:exec_input spawn=[{}, "sh /var/log/folderParser.sh"] mode=[:read] stderr=:discard

Comment: That log shows that the script is working. Do you see the same log with 1s intervals? Kindly add your script to your question along with `exec` config and the fluentd startup logs for about 10 seconds.

Comment: A new config file has been added.
Yes, I have tried without run interval, with 1s and 10s run interval and the result is the same. I am receiving this message: `fluent/log.rb:302:debug: Executing command title=:exec_input spawn=[{}, "sh /var/log/folderParser.sh"] mode=[:read] stderr=:discard` each time when script should be running.
1 time in the case when the run interval is not set,
each 1s in case if `run_interval 1s` and each 10s in case if `run_interval 10s`

Comment: Can you route exec's output to stdout to see its output? BTW, you need to use a different tag for exec because you don't want to route its output to the output plugin. That's why I mentioned `null` earlier. The output of `tail` should be routed to the output plugin.

Comment: Just tested with this config and it's working fine: `<source>
   @type exec
   command echo hello
   tag exec.*
   run_interval 2s
   <parse>
      @type none
   </parse>
</source>

<match exec.*>
  @type stdout
</match>`

Comment: Here are a few output logs: `2021-01-20 14:44:56 +0500 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:308:debug: Executing command title=:exec_input spawn=[{}, "echo hello"] mode=[:read] stderr=:discard
2021-01-20 14:44:56.554882165 +0500 exec.*: {"message":"hello"}
2021-01-20 14:44:58 +0500 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:308:debug: Executing command title=:exec_input spawn=[{}, "echo hello"] mode=[:read] stderr=:discard
2021-01-20 14:44:58.554173258 +0500 exec.*: {"message":"hello"}`

Comment: Regarding the script, add `pwd` as the first line to verify its path it's executing from. Maybe, you need to fix the paths. I have just tested with `echo hello` in a `test.sh` script and it's working fine as well. Sample log: `2021-01-20 14:55:43 +0500 [debug]: #0 fluent/log.rb:308:debug: Executing command title=:exec_input spawn=[{}, "sh ~/Downloads/test.sh"] mode=[:read] stderr=:discard
2021-01-20 14:55:43.383374108 +0500 exec.*: {"message":"hello"}`

Comment: My mistake... I have started a script from the wrong folder... Script and configuration are working now. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: It seems that my conclusion that all is working was too early/ I still need help...
Script is working. Here it is 
```

Comment: It is added to the description together with conig file.
But I received on my grafana dashboard all logs that was created after docker-compose file was started. Even if I have just current logs in the /lastLogs/logs folder I could see all logs in my grafana dashboard.

It seems that I do something wrong. 
At first I thought that it depends on parameter `read_from_head true`. But situation didn't changed without it.

Comment: I believe that [read_from_head](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#read_from_head) should be false in case you're interested in the latest logs that have been appended at its tail, not the head. You're removing and then copying all the stuff in that folder so that means it's all new. I believe that's why it's considering all of them due to the newly created folders and filers. You might want to verify it and then update accordingly.

Comment: I correct `read_from_head false`.
If I correct bash script and it doesn't remove all previous files from the folder and just load the latest files to that folder I still have all files that were collected after docker-compose file was started.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood all of that. Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: For example, if I start the app for the first time it will create 4 logs file in /lastLogs/logs folder and I will see just these files in my dashboard. This is exactly what I need.
When I start the app next time, the next 4 logs are moved to the /lastLogs/logs folder and I see on my dashboard logs from this and the previous app runs. But I need only logs from the last app run on this dashboard.
The result is the same as when I removing and copying files to the folder.

Comment: So, fluentd is running with its `exec` and `tail` input plugins. Your app runs, it generates logs, and those are copied to the target folder. You get the logs. Now, for the second time when it runs, it generates more logs, those logs are copied; but, the logs that are sent out also include the previous logs as well, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The previous logs are sent again. Is this what you're observing?

Comment: At the second time, when app running it still generates the same number of logs and only those 4 logs are copied to the destination folder. Previous logs already exist in the destination folder and are not modified. According to the received fluend logs, only the last app logs are sent to the grafana after they are copied to the destination folder. 
But the logs that are in grafana dashboard include the last logs and previous logs.

Comment: Right. If only the required logs are sent then it sounds like that the previous logs have already been sent and stored on the other side. I guess it needs some handling from the dashboard side. Do you think that something may be done from fluentd's side here?

Comment: I had such thoughts, but now I don't sure...
If there is no such possibility in fluentd then I will try to found it on Grafana dashboard side.

Comment: I believe we cannot do anything about the logs that have already been dispatched from fluentd. So, it's logical to check the destination for such configurations.

Comment: Yes.
Thanks for your time and your help :)

Comment: Sure thing. It's been a pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be to:

- use the `exec` input plugin with a shell script.
- The shell script will evaluate and move the latest files to a predefined path/location.
- You can `tail` this predefined path for new files.
- Also, route the output of `exec` to `null`.